# Скрапинг рандомной картинки по запросу в гугл

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, поисковые-системы

Я хотел бы попробовать реализовать бота который будет по кодовому слову искать картинки и отправлять. Но я не знаю как реализовать момент скрапинга и выбора картинки.

Я пробовал что то подобное

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

r = s.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=яблоко&tbm=isch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for text in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'wXeWr islib nfEiy'}):
    print(text)
```

Но это не сработало, да и если бы сработало я не могу понять как реализовать механизм выбора рандомной ссылки. Для кого то это может быть не сложно. прошу помочь новокеку) Я посмотрел уже пару модулей для выбора рангдомных картинок, но там не по запросу.
Заранее большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Выбор рандомного элемента из списка будет такой (тут только код с выбором):

```py
import random

images = soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'wXeWr islib nfEiy'})
print(random.choice(images))
```

Comment: как бы все верно, но выводится рандомный полный код ячейки с картинкой.

Comment: но и на этом большое спасибо)